# Updating Properties of a Report - OrderBy and Filter

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to have another form do sorting and filtering but I can't seem to change the properties and I am getting an error 438 (`Object doesn't support this property or method`)

Looking for a possible alternative.

`[Forms]![Form-Main]![zSubForm-1]![SubFormReport-Form1].OrderBy = "[Form1_Number] ASC"`

`[Forms]![Form-Main]![zSubForm-1]![SubFormReport-Form1].Filter = "Me.txtFilterBox"`

I'm triggering this via a Button.

Comment: Title says Report but narrative says Form. Which line errors? Don't put reference to textbox in quote marks. What field do you want to filter on? What data type? `= "fieldname = " & Me.txtFilterBox`. What is [Form1_Number] - a field or control?

Comment: You have a report embedded on a form? What is zSubForm-1 - a subform/subreport container control? Is SubFormReport-Form1 name of report?

Comment: Yes. The report is embedded in that form. The data type is `Short Text`

Comment: [Form1_Number] is the header from a table, which the report is referenced from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference subform/subreport through container control but don't actually use subform/subreport name. Don't put reference to textbox within quote marks. If field to filter on is text type, use apostrophe delimiters.

Syntax to use is:
Forms!mainformName!subformcontainerName.Report.OrderBy
Forms!mainformName!subformcontainerName.Report.Filter

Consider:

```
[Forms]![Form-Main]![zSubForm-1].Report.OrderBy = "[Form1_Number] ASC"

[Forms]![Form-Main]![zSubForm-1].Report.Filter = "somefieldname='" & Me.txtFilterBox & "'"
```

Be aware any Sorting & Grouping settings in report design will override OrderBy property and code will be ignored. Filter can still be programmatically changed.

Comment: Getting the same error, 438 with this syntax for the OrderBy